# Setting default Time Zone for DateTimes

Tags: c#, datetime, internationalization, timezone

I have an C# application that will be running in a different timezone than where I am developing it. It uses time-based data, and performs calculations and makes decisions based on the time-based data. I want to test using the real data, so was wondering how I could set the time zone or something similar of the application as if I was in the other timezone, and all variables of type DateTime would use this default time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just change the timezone on your machine, which is getting picked up by the `DateTime` class. 
As a general recommendation I would do all time related calculations and storing of times in UTC, only for display purposes convert to the local time zone.

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime` has only three "modes": `DateTimeKind.Utc`, `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` and `DateTimeKind.Local`. It doesn't make calculations based on the time zone. It doesn't offset it in any way. There is a `DateTimeOffset` that could help you (starting with .NET 2.0 SP2)

Answer (score 1):

Is the [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) class available to you? (it is not when you use the compact framework). Judging from its APIs, it seems to cover your requirements very well.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the time zone of the computer that is running the application.